# How do I to set Gmail as default email program in Windows 10?

Tags: gmail

I use Gmail as my default email client. What do I have to do to have  `mailto:x@y.com` open Gmail instead of opening the standard Windows email program?

Comment: It may depend on the browser you're using.

Answer (score 3):

When using Google Chrome check the following link: http://lifehacker.com/5883372/set-gmail-as-your-browsers-default-email-client-with-a-simple-hack

Basically the following:

Open Gmail in Chrome. Press Ctrl+Shift+J (Windows) or Cmd+Opt+J (Mac) to open Chrome's built-in JavaScript console.

Paste the following into the console and press Enter:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto", "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s", "Gmail");
```

Chrome will prompt you, asking if you'd like to "Allow Gmail (mail.google.com) to open all email links?"

Click the Use Gmail button.

That's it!

Comment: Shouldn't need to use a console window hack. It should be right there in the settings. Let me see if I can track that down.

Comment: I believe chrome will ask it eventually when using gmail repetitively

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the program you're trying to send the email from. Unfortunately, some programs are designed to work only with the native email clients. A [supported solution](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) (IMAP is for sending & receiving) for this is to configure Outlook or the native client with your cloud-based email service, make sure to set your [default email accordingly](https://www.lifewire.com/set-default-account-outlook-1173707). one thing to note, if you use two-way authentication, you'll need to generate an app-specific password.